How can I fix the “Katalon Studio not responding” issue when launching the program?
•   When I try to open Katalon Studio, I sometimes get the message “Katalon Studio not responding” or the program stops responding completely.
•   The issue occurs randomly when I try to launch the program, and it freezes for a few minutes without allowing me to interact with it.
•   I am using Windows 10 with the latest updates, and the version of Katalon Studio I’m using is 8.4.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
What I tried:
•   I tried restarting Katalon Studio several times.
•   I also restarted my computer to see if that would help resolve the issue.
•   I ran Katalon Studio as an administrator to check if it was a permission issue.
•   I ensured that my Katalon Studio version and Java are up-to-date.
•   I checked if any other programs or background processes were using too much system resources.

What I was expecting:
•   I was expecting Katalon Studio to open without any issues and to be able to start working on my tests without any delays or freezes.
•   I also expected the issue to resolve after restarting the program or the computer, as it’s usually a common fix for similar problems.


Have you contacted the Katalon Customer Support?

May be you can try to Close other programs to reduce system resource usage, temporarily disable your antivirus software to check if it's causing the issue, check the logs for any errors, uninstall and reinstall Katalon Studio to fix any corrupted files, and update Java to ensure compatibility with Katalon Studio.
If the problem persists, there may be a deeper system or installation issue.
